# Can not insert text in bookmark in word document using office.js for office add-in development

Tags: office365, office-js

I am developing an add-in for word.The main task is to populate the bookmarks in a document with data from the database.In office.js all i have found that a bookmark can be accessed as a range object and i am using "rangeObject.insertText(text, insertLocation)" method for inserting data into a bookmark.But the problem is 2nd parameter insertLocation value can be 'Replace', 'Start', 'End', 'Before' or 'After'.Which basically appends the data before or after the bookmark.like this -
[image 1 (current result using insertLocation value 'End')](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l1k9P.jpg)

using insertLocation value 'Replace' it replaces the whole bookmark and actually deletes the bookmark from the document!.So all i want is insert a text in the bookmark like this-
[image 2 (desired result)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d79hO.jpg)

Note: I have to read these bookmark value later.So no bookmark can be deleted.and i am using 1.4 beta version of the office.js api for purpose.

Here is my code-

```
        Word.run(function (context) {

            var doc = context.document;

            //get the bookmark range by its name
            var bookmarkRange = doc.getBookmarkRangeOrNullObject("cscasenumber01");

            //insert a data
            bookmarkRange.insertText("test data",'end');


            // Synchronize the document state by executing the queued commands, 
            return context.sync();

        }).catch(errorHandler);
```

Answer (score 2):

After reviewing this issue we just found that the "Replace"  behavior is by design.

In fact if you use directly the UI to replace the text of a range containing the bookmark, the bookmark will be deleted. The same is true if you do it programmatically with a Macro/VBA.

The good news is that after replacing the text, the selection will be the replaced text range, so you could re-create the bookmark after the replace operation, if so needed.

Note that this only happens with replace. Inserting on Start or End will keep the bookmark.

Finally the Bookmark API is still in preview and has an unknown release date.

--------- Keeping some context of the previews answer ---------

thanks so much for using our preview APIs.  I just repro this behavior, and its by design. And yes the semantics for before, start, end, after are very clear on the API.

1. "Start" and "End" insert locations imply that the insertions will be within the boundaries of the calling Range, on this case means that if you use any of those the bookmark needs to be expanded to whatever is inserted.
2. On the other hand "Before"/"After" imply inserting outside the boundaries of the range.
3. Finally, replace should replace the bookmark with whatever text supplied as parameter, the bookmark will be removed (in consistency with doing it directly in the UI and programmatically with VBA).

thank you

Comment: Please fix the bug as soon as possible.Because we have a major feature dependent on it in our add-in.We also have a deadline to meet.Thanks.

Comment: Just to set expectations properly, this is a preview API and you should not take any dependency on this for production purposes  until we move it to production. That date is at this point unknown.

Comment: @JuanBalmori is this fixed, whats the planned date for production of office js