# Can not replace bookmark in word document using office.js

Tags: office-js

I am developing an add-in for word. I am trying to replace a bookmark with a text. (My initial target was to insert text in the bookmark but there is a bug in the API so this is the alternate approach. [Earlier question link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45690738/can-not-insert-text-in-bookmark-in-word-document-using-office-js-for-office-add))

Here is my code:

```
Word.run(function (context) {

    var doc = context.document;

    //get the bookmark range object by its name
    var bookmarkRange=doc.getBookmarkRangeOrNullObject("cscasenumber01");

    //insert a data and replace thee bookmark range
    bookmarkRange.insertText("test data",Word.InsertLocation.replace);

    // Synchronize the document state by executing the queued commands, 
    return context.sync();

}).catch(errorHandler);
```

But it throws exception. The error trace message is:

> "GeneralException: GeneralException at Anonymous function
>   (https://appsforoffice.microsoft.com/lib/beta/hosted/word-win32-16.01.js:21:211625)
>   at ai
>   (https://appsforoffice.microsoft.com/lib/beta/hosted/word-win32-16.01.js:21:248841)
>   at ft
>   (https://appsforoffice.microsoft.com/lib/beta/hosted/word-win32-16.01.js:21:248928)
>   at d
>   (https://appsforoffice.microsoft.com/lib/beta/hosted/word-win32-16.01.js:21:248748)
>   at c
>   (https://appsforoffice.microsoft.com/lib/beta/hosted/word-win32-16.01.js:21:247444)"

So is there any solution for it or it is another bug in the API ?

Note: I am using 1.4 beta version of the office.js API.

Comment: Can you using the released version of the api?

Answer (score 1):

You need to test for whether bookmarkRange is a null object. Please try this code:

```
var bookmarkRange=doc.getBookmarkRangeOrNullObject("cscasenumber01");
bookmarkRange.load();

return context.sync()
.then(function() {
   if (bookmarkRange.isNullObject) {
        // handle case of null object here
   } else {
        bookmarkRange.insertText("test data",Word.InsertLocation.replace);
   }
})
.then(context.sync)
```

Comment: Yes. It does not give null object.I have tested your code but no luck.Still it is giving the same exception.